# What are the possible reasons for getting blank GCM Registration Id only in some android devices?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using GCM registration in my Android App.

What I do is:

> a) I initiate GCM registration in onCreate of launch screen, of my
>   app.
>
> b) Then on a button click I send this gcm registration Id to server.

Now, what's happening is,

On some android devices, I'm getting a blank GCM registration Id, while on others, this is working perfectly fine.

Can you please suggest, what may be the possible causes for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. No internet. 2. Google Play Services not ready for example Google Play Account not logged in. 3. GCM Server was too busy and can't handle the request etc etc

Comment: All devices have Google Play Services?